# How would you loop through files in a directory and compare them to each other?

Tags: bash, shell, diff

I never do bash scripts so I have no clue the most efficient way to do this and quickly. I know how I would do it in something like python or c++.

I have a file structure like the one below:

```
-parentDir
   --subDir1
      ---file1.txt
      ---file2.txt
      ---file3.txt
      ---file4.txt
   --subDir2
      ---file1.txt
      ---file2.txt
      ---file3.txt
      ---file4.txt
```

There could be any number of subdirectories and text files.

Basically I would like to create a bash script that goes into each subdirectory and then compares using `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` using diff and then compare `file2.txt` and `file3.txt` and so on outputting the difference to the end of a txt file.

I know how to use diff to compare files and then outputting the difference to a txt file I just do not know how to do what I envision as a double for loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a double `for` loop. You're just comparing each file to the next file, not to all the other files. Or did you describe it wrong?

Comment: Is it always just 2 levels of nesting, or do you have to do it recursively for any depth?

Comment: Maybe you could show us how you would do it in python then. Because otherwise your description is lacking clarty like (should you compare files across sub-directories?, are-there only text files? are text files always with same .txt suffix? where to output the diffs, with what names...)

Comment: I was thinking a double for only because I see it something like "for each dir the parent directory and then for each file in dir compare to the next file" @Bamar

Comment: Put the filenames in an array, then you can iterate over the array indexes, and use `diff ${array[$i]} ${array[$i+1]}`

Comment: @newwebdev22 You're right about that. I thought you meant a double loop for the two files being compared.

Comment: `for dir in parentDir/*; do for file in "$dir"/*.txt; do ...; done; done`

Comment: I understand how to loop through a directory by doing something like for fname in *:do [something] done. I understand to output the difference to a file by using something like diff a.txt b.txt > c.txt. I am confused on how to actually write out compare the first and second file and then the second and third file and so on.

Comment: Surely you don't want to compare fileA with fileB, then later fileB with fileA. So on your main loop for fileA over the all files array minus the last entry, your inner iteration for fileB starts at the index of fileA + 1 and ends at the last file in the files array....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

typeset -r diffs=diffs.txt
typeset -a allfiles=()
typeset -- filename=''

# fills the allfiles array with all *.txt files except the diffs.txt
# that can be found from the current directory and down all sub-directories
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  allfiles+=("$filename")
done < <(
  find . -type f -name '*.txt' -and -not -name "$diffs" -print0 2>/dev/null
)

[[ ${#allfiles[@]} -lt 2 ]] && exit 2 # Need at least 2 files to compare

typeset -i i=0 j=0
typeset -- file_a='' file_b=''
export LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
# for all files except last
for ((i = 0; i < ${#allfiles[@]} - 1; i++)); do
  file_a="${allfiles[$i]}"
  # for next file to last file
  for ((j = i + 1; j < ${#allfiles[@]}; j++)); do
    file_b="${allfiles[$j]}"
    diff --report-identical-files --unified=0 --minimal -- \
      "$file_a" "$file_b" 2>/dev/null
    echo
  done
done >"$diffs" # all output to the diffs file
```